# (invalid lvalue in assignment) this error happens when i run it.what does it mean?

Tags: c, compiler-errors, ternary-operator, conditional-operator

### this is the code and the compiler says there is sth wrong with line 7.

```
include<stdio.h>
main()
{
char m;
 int a,b,n=0;
scanf("%c%d%d",&m,&a,&b);
m=='A' || m=='B' || m=='C' ? n=(3*a)+(5*b) : n=(5*a)+(3*b);
printf("%d\n",n);
}
```

Comment: It was interpreted like `(m=='A' || m=='B' || m=='C' ? n=(3*a)+(5*b) : n) =(5*a)+(3*b);`.Try `n=(5*a)+(3*b)` --> `(n=(5*a)+(3*b))` or `n = m=='A' || m=='B' || m=='C' ? 3*a + 5*b : 5*a + 3*b;
`

Comment: Don't hesitate to put brackets, it's not a shame, even when you're 100% sure about order of operators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use instead

```
m=='A' || m=='B' || m=='C' ? n=(3*a)+(5*b) : ( n=(5*a)+(3*b));
```

Otherwise the statement looks like

```
( m=='A' || m=='B' || m=='C' ? n=(3*a)+(5*b) : n)=(5*a)+(3*b);
```

Or you could write

```
n = m=='A' || m=='B' || m=='C' ? (3*a)+(5*b) : (5*a)+(3*b);
```

The conditional operator in C is defined the following way

```
conditional-expression:
    logical-OR-expression
    logical-OR-expression ? expression : conditional-expression
```

As the assignment operator has lower priority then the compiler issues an error because the assignment is excluded from the conditional operator for the third operand

The used by you expression would be valid in C++ because in C++ the operator is defined differently

```
conditional-expression:
    logical-or-expression
    logical-or-expression ? expression : assignment-expression
                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: i tried (n=(5*a)+(3*b)) instead of n=(5*a)+(3*b) and (n=(3*a)+(5*b)) instead of  n=(3*a)+(5*b)  and it debugged.thanks for ur help!

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use a complicated statement that confuses everyone, including the compiler. This is just as effective, and a lot easier to read:

```
if (m=='A' || m=='B' || m=='C')
   n=(3*a)+(5*b);
else
   n=(5*a)+(3*b);
```